# PowerBI - Match Value from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables where they are connected by **Table1[ColA] &Table1[ColB]**.

Now I am trying to match the values from **Table1[ColB]** with **Table2[ColB]** & return the result in Table2[ColC]. 
Where the result should be -

```
if it matches "Found"
doesn't match "Not-Found"
else Empty
```

Table1

```
ColA    ColB   ColC 
11        AA
12        BB
13
```

Table2

```
ColA    ColB
11        DD
12        CC
13        BB
```

**Expected Output**
Table1

```
ColA    ColB   ColC 
11        AA   Not-Found
12        BB   Found
13        CC   Empty
```

Do anyone knows any solution to this problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with a calculated column like this in Table 1.

```
Col_C = 
         Var out1 = LOOKUPVALUE(Table2[ColB],Table2[ColB],Table1[ColB])
         Var out2 = IF(out1 = "", "Not Found","Found")
         Var out3 = if(Table1[ColB] = "", "Empty", out2)
return out3
```

*`The Key is to use Use the LOOKUPVALUE function to see, if the value exists.`*

[image]

*Kindly accept the answer if it helps to solve your problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Are this tables related? Then you could do the following column formula:

```
ColC = IF(ISBLANK(related(Table2[ColB]), "Not-Found", IF(Table1[ColB] = related(Table2[ColB]), "Found", "Empty"))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am receiving this error while trying your query - Too many arguments were passed to the RELATED function. The maximum argument count for the function is 1.

Comment: Did you try it in TableA? Its a column formula for TableA, I edited my post, there was also a syntax error

Comment: i have tried it on TableA, but still receiving the same error message